# Object not loading when I add `Load_Event`

Tags: c#, asp.net, onload-event

The object I'm using is `<asp:Chart/>`. I built it using Visual Web Developper 2010's binding tool:

[image]

I changed the look and behavior with the `properties` pannel and a CSS sheet. Everything was coming out fine until I accidently double-clicked on the chart. This added a `myChart_Load` method to my code. Now if I boot my page with the empty chart load method, my chart disappears from the screen as if it was only looking in the `chart_load` to see what to do, see nothing then don't show anything, forgetting the binding tool and properties/CSS.

Then if I delete

```
protected void myChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

the empty load above, the compiler crashes and says it is expecting a load method. Any idea why it's behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about why adding a Load handler it doesn't come back, but it's erroring now because in the markup, it added the event handler reference there `OnLoad="myChart_Load"`, so it looks for this, can't find it, and throws an exception.

Comment: How can I access this line, delete it. And let it load like it did before ?

Comment: +1 Something tells me though, even after removing the reference it'll come up blank. I can't imagine why an empty event handler being attached would cause it to stop rendering.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk If there's nothing in the properties (events) pane for the chart, you'll have to go into the code file and delete it yourself.

Comment: I did it. I don't get the error anymore but still my chart isn't there anymore.. I guess my problem is elsewhere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the method from code behind by just deleting it. you'll also have to remove the reference of the method found in the .designer.cs file.